# How can I detect the inclination of a line "crossing" a pixel in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab

I have a binary image of a fingerprint and I need to be able to find the orientation for the pixels corresponding to the minutiae.
Is there a way to get the inclination of the tangent line *crossing* a pixel located in a ridge?

My MATLAB version is R2012a.

**Binary fingerprint image:-**

[image: here]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The link created by Peter kovesi below provides code for orientation field and minutia extraction for matching:- http://www.csse.uwa.edu.au/~pk/research/matlabfns/

You can also use the SDK. If I am not mistaken its called FingerJet.

Comment: I'd forgotten about this page ... lots of goodies. Interesting to see Peter Kovesi is also among the people slowly switching to Julia :)

Comment: Make sure you do region segmentation to prevent false minutia appearing in noisy backgrounds.